# How to set a gradient using CAGradientLayer to a UIView (subview) in swift programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview, cagradientlayer

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.addSubview(container)
        container.customAcnhor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, height: 350)
        
    }

    let container : UIView = {
        var view = UIView()
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = view.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
        view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        
        return view
    }()
}
```

## Code Context

The above class has a **container** which it is of type **UIView** where it contains a **CAGradientLayer**. I am trying to display the gradient to a **subview** where I am adding this container(subview) to the main view.
Below is a similar example on how I want to achieve this. The blue colour on the image needs to have my custom gradient.
can some one please help me to solve this problem?

[image: I want the gradient to be on the blue part of the sub-view as something similar shown in the image.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to set the frame of `gradient layer` once again after laying out the `container view`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.addSubview(container)
        container.customAcnhor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, height: 350)
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    }
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    lazy var container : UIView = {
        var view = UIView()
        view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        return view
    }()
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        gradient.frame = container.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: this makes the entire screen with gradient. but I just want just part of the screen. like the gradient should be applied only on the blue part of the screen like shown in above image.

Comment: are you setting `gradient.frame = container.bounds`?

Comment: yes, I did that but it still shows me a blank screen.

Comment: Are you sure your view is being displayed properly?

Comment: yes, when I try to do ```gradient.frame = view.bounds``` I get the entire screen with gradient but when I try to do ```gradient.frame = container.bounds``` it just shows blank screen on the simulator.

Comment: I asked to check if the `container` is getting displayed properly.

Comment: I changed the ```container``` background image using ```view.backgroundColor = .blue``` and it displays as it's shown in the above image. but when I take off the background colour, nothing changes.

Comment: Did you get this to work because I am having the same problem?